# Accessing web request globally in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I need to be able to access the currently executing web request in Tornado deep within my application without passing it down through all of my methods. When the request is first received I want to assign a trace id to it and then every time a message gets logged I want to include it in the logging information.

Is there some global information somewhere that I can use in Tornado to identify the current request that's being processed?

Thanks!

Comment: Tornado is single threaded, so if you launch only one tornado process, it is possible to store information in some global variable i suppose.

Comment: Right, but doesn't it follow the event machine pattern where it uses the same thread but does context switching? I need to know when those switches occur.

Comment: As far as i know, tornado will create new `RequestHandler` instance for each request

Comment: Right, but it's a non-blocking web server so it uses one thread and switches back-and-forth between requests right? If that's the case, how do I know which request it's processing at any given time?

Comment: Don't do this. It is bad. Global state is bad. Just pass the request as a parameter where you need it.

Comment: Yes, I know global state can be bad. What I'm trying to avoid though is adding the request object to every single method so I can access it. In django it's easy because I can use `theading.local()` to store the info, but I can't in tornado.

Answer (score 6):

Tornado's [StackContext](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.3/stack_context.html) is the way to do this.

Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/simon-weber/7755289.

Comment: the problem with StackContext is that it was remove from Tornado 6.0